# jQuery dataTable server side searching not working if text content single quotes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Here I'm facing problem is, I'm doing server side dataTable filter after insert text in datable search box which content single quotes eg-(**Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.**) if this text I'm giving in search text box and I'm trying to filter from server side then I'm getting error.

in below I'm mentioning my action method code

```
string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
searchValue = searchValue.Trim();
v = db.Database.SqlQuery<ListViewModel>("select EL.Id,USR.FullName as UsrName,case when EL.E_Message is null or EL.E_Message = '' then '--Message Not Found--'  else EL.E_Message end as E_Message,case when EL.InnerException is null or EL.InnerException = ''  then '--Not Found--'  else EL.InnerException end as InnerException,EL.DateTimeErrorLogged, case when C.name is null then '--No Company Found--'  else C.name end as company from s_ErrorLogs EL inner join AspNetUsers USR on EL.UserID = USR.Id Left join company C on EL.Company_Id = C.id  where USR.FullName LIKE '%'" + searchValue + "'%' or E_Message LIKE '%'" + searchValue + "'%' or EL.InnerException LIKE '%'" + searchValue + "'%' or EL.DateTimeErrorLogged LIKE '%'" + searchValue + "'%' or C.name LIKE '%'" + searchValue + "'%' order by EL.Id");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to Replace your string containing ' (1 single quotes)  by '' (2 single quotes) ......**

```
 string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
searchValue = searchValue.Trim();
v = db.Database.SqlQuery<ListViewModel>("select EL.Id,USR.FullName as UsrName,case when EL.E_Message is null or EL.E_Message = '' then '--Message Not Found--'  else EL.E_Message end as E_Message,case when EL.InnerException is null or EL.InnerException = ''  then '--Not Found--'  else EL.InnerException end as InnerException,EL.DateTimeErrorLogged, case when C.name is null then '--No Company Found--'  else C.name end as company from s_ErrorLogs EL inner join AspNetUsers USR on EL.UserID = USR.Id Left join company C on EL.Company_Id = C.id  where USR.FullName LIKE '%'" + searchValue.Replace(''','''') + "'%' or E_Message LIKE '%'" + searchValue.Replace(''','''') + "'%' or EL.InnerException LIKE '%'" + searchValue.Replace(''','''') + "'%' or EL.DateTimeErrorLogged LIKE '%'" + searchValue.Replace(''','''') + "'%' or C.name LIKE '%'" + searchValue.Replace(''','''') + "'%' order by EL.Id");
```

Comment: ERRO:syntax error in or next to "'mn'"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 26 ? Is this ur error????

Comment: i modified your code and now its working thnaks eg i am shown for others 
  -----where USR.FullName LIKE '%"+ searchValue.Replace("'","''") +"%' or E_Message LIKE '%"+ searchValue.Replace("'", "''") +"%'

Answer (score 0):

i modified your code and now its working thanks eg i am shown for others -----where USR.FullName LIKE '%"+ searchValue.Replace("'","''") +"%' or E_Message LIKE '%"+ searchValue.Replace("'", "''") +"%'